# Volume object create artifacts in Eevee render

Tags: rendering, materials, eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

Volume for some reason turns white on the render. And also this white artifact on the left, as if I forgot to hide some object, but there is nothing there.

Volume Shader

[image]

I don't have a background in the form of an object, only the world shader.

[image]

floor with a mask so that it disappears around the edges

[image]
[image]

Viewport Eevee

[image: Viewport Eevee]

Render Eevee

[image: Render Eevee]